# Why the XMLHTTPRequest run in last iteration of loop ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code that should send request in each iteration of loop, but it runs in last iteration , Why ?

```
function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('price');
        var PID = document.getElementsByName('product');
        var tot = 0;
        var xml ;

        for ( j=0; j<PID.length; j++){

            xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xml.onreadystatechange=function()
                {   
                    if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200){
                        for( i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                            if(parseInt(arr[i].value)){
                                tot += xml.responseText * arr[i].value;
                                document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                xml.open("POST","http://localhost/CRM/mr/getPrice/"+PID[j].value);
                xml.send();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: can you do a `console.log(PID[j].value)` inside the loop to be you are getting all the values you expect?

Comment: give me : event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: If that is all you see then the either the loop isn't running at all or you console.log is outside of the loop, or you havn't yet run `findTotal`

Comment: I run finalTotal with onblur in input, but I see number series of loop but I didn't expect that

Comment: Try removing that first `console.log` and adding a new one just under `tot+=xml.responseText * arr[i].value;` that says `console.log(tot)` to see if you are getting the `responseText` every time as you expect.

Comment: I noticed it run correctly but it sends new request with previous one Not close the previous

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `onstatechange` for just one `xml` object over and over again, you want to create a new `xml` object for each iteration.  move  the `xml = new XMLHttpRequest();` statement inside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new XMLHttpRequest object for each of your requests as the previous one most likely has not finished.

> open()
>
> ...
>
> Note: Calling this method for an already active request (one for which open() or openRequest() has already been called) is the equivalent of calling abort().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information on what the new(?) problem is.